# Shared library under Windows and CMake: DLL not found before installation

Tags: windows, dll, cmake

The library `mylib` consists of the library proper, in directory `lib/`, and a test suite, in directory `test/`. It is completely under CMake control:

```
mylib/CMakeLists.txt:
...
add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(test)
...


mylib/lib/CMakeLists.txt:
...
add_library(my_lib ${src_files})
...


mylib/test/CMakeLists.txt:
...
add_executable(mytest mytest.c)
target_link_libraries(mytest mylib)
```

Build steps are:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
ctest         # or make test
make install
```

Works under Linux, stable since many years. Under Windows10 though, a message window pops up, entitled "mytest.exe - System error": "The code execution cannot proceed because mylib.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

No, installing (rather than reinstalling) would not be a good solution: I need to first test the library before I install it (btw: this excludes most solutions proposed in response to somewhat similar questions).

Isn't CMake supposed to work cross-platform? What is the minimally invasive adjustment to make the above build steps work under Windows?

Answer (score 3):

The right way of doing this on Windows is to populate the `PATH` environment variable for the test run:

```
set_tests_properties(your_test_name
  PROPERTIES
      ENVIRONMENT PATH="path-containing-your-dll")
```

I believe you can use generator expression if `path-containing-your-dll` is a function of an artifact that you generate in your build.

Cherry on top: since cmake 3.13, the variable `VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT` can also be set on the target for having a nice debugging behaviour inside Visual Studio (eg. being able to debug the application directly from Visual instead of going through `ctest`).

Comment: Is there any reference that expands on this? Explains why this is _the_ right way?

Comment: Windows relies on several cues for finding DLLs. The lesser-intrusive one is by changing the `PATH` environment variables, the others are, if I recall, placing those DLL in some specific folders of the operating system. `PATH` offers the most flexible way by decoupling the physical location of the DLLs (what your cmake wants to do) from Windows mechanisms for finding those. This is why I believe this is the right way: mimicking the expected behaviour of Windows with minimal constraints on your application.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications for more details.